# Custom formula returning #NAME when Google Sheets is published to web

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function, web-publishing

I'm not much of a programmer, but I managed to write a Google Sheets script that sorts an array, filters out specified values, and returns the new array. It works great.

However, when I publish the output page to the web, the link will only successfully show the output if I have the back end sheet open. As soon as I close it, the publish page turns up #NAME.

Presumably there is some restriction as to the availability of custom scripts. I assumed the output would just grab the text, but I suppose it's trying to run it and can't without someone being logged in?

Anyways - is there some way around this?

Thanks

Edit: Did a little further reading and found out that this might be a situation where "script as web app" might be the requirement. As a novice, this is a little over my head and I'd appreciate any advice.

I also tested to make sure `IMPORTRANGE()` as a source for this data wasn't the issue, and though it may cause other problems once I get the #name issue resolved, it does not appear to be at fault here specifically since the same thing happens with local data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you've stated, [script as web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) might be the requirement. You may also want to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) regarding *Custom Functions in Google Sheets*. Just be noted that a script can be published as a web app if it meets these requirements:

- It contains a `doGet(e)` or `doPost(e)` function.
- The function returns an [HTML service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html) [`HtmlOutput`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output) object or a [Content service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content) [`TextOutput`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/text-output) object.

Hope this helps!